# My question is different, but it was merged. and now i want to unmerge it..

Tags: discussion, merge

my question is here.. 
[is it possible to make nautilus open with two panes by default?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/196177/is-it-possible-to-make-nautilus-open-with-two-panes-by-default)

i ask in my question text to find specifically other solutions than the xdotool workaround, and also i use 12.04  not a previous version like the other question does (and the other question can be answered with something that was present then and not present now in nautilus prefs) so yes my question is unique and different.. 
 so  please unmerge my question ..  read up on the chat to see the discussion that lead to me posting this in meta.. 
thanks.

Comment: Think the questions are the same, even though the answer merged in to the main one does not please everyone. I can understand that. Can I suggest you add a bounty to the question explaining that any solution not using `xdotool` would be worthy of it?

Answer (score 8):

I'd say **don't unmerge**. While the questions differ, they *only* do so in the version of ubuntu used, and the resulting difference in `nautilus`.

A much better solution, in my opinion, would be a **canonical question** with multiple answers branching depending on the version used.

The question itself is the same in both cases: **"How to make nautilus open with two panes by default?"**

Comment: the question is the same.. because i changed the title in the old one.. (look in edits.. you'll see)

Comment: @marc-andrebenoit I'm saying that both questions boil down to exactly the same question.